# disable all touch events in a view and its children

Tags: android, view

I have a fragment that return `View fView` on its getview() method.
Now in some cases I need to disable all touch events on the screen and after a while I enable it.

I searched and I found some methods that not worked for me like `setClickable(false)` and `setEnable(flase)` and override `setOnTouchListener` but non of them not worked.

I need a method which disable all the touchevents such as scrolling clicking on buttons and ... .

thank you for your attention.

Comment: need to over ride that view and over onInterceptTouchEvent method of that view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12977997/1444191